# Loading image not working when image.crosOrigin="annonymous"

Tags: javascript, html, cross-origin-read-blocking

So I am trying to load an image from a URL as such (this.path contains the link of the image):

```
 let image = new Image()
    image.onload = () => {
      console.log('loaded')
    }
    image.src = this.path
```

the Images are loaded to my page however when loading as above the images are marked as tainted and therefore I cant extract pixel data from them. So I tried the following:

```
 let image = new Image()
    image.onload = () => {
      console.log('loaded')
    }
    image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
    image.src = this.path
```

With the above code I get now the following CORS Blocked error 
`Access to image at 'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2559551.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

and the image does not load anymore
(I noticed that [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg) link works any other doesn't)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to configure the server to allow requests from your localhost.  Someone will probably have a dupe CORS post here soon enough.

Comment: I do not have a server i just run `npm run serve` with NodeJS

Comment: `https://wallpapercave.com`/wp/wp2559551.jpg <= the image is coming from a server.  That server must be configured to allow your request from localhost.

Comment: It is a random image from the internet

Comment: I need to load images from other websites